# MySQL: Select MAX() from sub-query with COUNT()

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

Before you mark this as duplicate please take a look at this [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/336d6/1).

I have this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE book(book_id int,
                   book_name varchar(100),
                   author_id int,
                   editor_id varchar(100),
                   isbn varchar(100));
INSERT INTO book
VALUES
(1 , 'Book1 Title' ,  12  ,  'Editor1'   , '8000-9000' ),
(2 , 'Book2 Title' ,  98  ,  'Editor1'   , '8000-9001' ),
(1 , 'Book1 Title' ,  12  ,  'Editor1'   , '8000-9002' ),
(3 , 'Book3 Title' ,  3  ,  'Editor1'   , '8000-9003' );

CREATE TABLE author(author_id int,
                    fn varchar(100),
                    ln varchar(100));
INSERT INTO author
VALUES
(12, 'name1','lname1'),
(98,'name2','lname2'),
(3,'name3','lname3');
```

The sub-query:

```
  SELECT c.author_id,COUNT(*) book_count FROM book c
  GROUP BY c.author_id
```

has a result:

```
| AUTHOR_ID | BOOK_COUNT |
--------------------------
|         3 |          1 |
|        12 |          2 |
|        98 |          1 |
```

Now, the tricky part here is the result of this query:

```
SELECT MAX(book_count),a.* FROM
author a,(
  SELECT c.author_id,COUNT(*) book_count FROM book c
  GROUP BY c.author_id
) b 
where a.author_id = b.author_id
```

is this:

```
| MAX(BOOK_COUNT) | AUTHOR_ID |    FN |     LN |
------------------------------------------------
|               2 |         3 | name3 | lname3 |
```

which should be like this:

```
| MAX(BOOK_COUNT) | AUTHOR_ID |    FN |     LN |
------------------------------------------------
|               2 |        12 | name1 | lname1 |
```

What do you think is wrong in the query?

Comment: How are you getting `FN` and `LN` in your result without selecting it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `MAX()` you can simply use `LIMIT` for the same. Also use `JOIN` instead.

```
SELECT book_count,a.author_id,a.fn, a.ln 
FROM author a
JOIN
(
  SELECT c.author_id,COUNT(*) book_count FROM book c
  GROUP BY c.author_id
) b 
ON a.author_id = b.author_id
ORDER BY book_count DESC LIMIT 1
```

Output:

```
| BOOK_COUNT | AUTHOR_ID |    FN |     LN |
-------------------------------------------
|          2 |        12 | name1 | lname1 |
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/336d6/16)

---

**Edit:**

If you want to use `MAX()` for that, you have to use sub-query like this:

```
SELECT book_count,a.author_id,a.fn, a.ln 
FROM author a
JOIN
(
  SELECT c.author_id,COUNT(*) book_count FROM book c
  GROUP BY c.author_id
) b 
ON a.author_id = b.author_id
WHERE book_count = 
        (SELECT MAX(book_count)
        FROM
        (
           SELECT c.author_id,COUNT(*) book_count FROM book c 
           GROUP BY c.author_id
        ) b )
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/336d6/40)

---

**Edit2:**

Instead of using `LIMIT` in outer query you can simply use it in inner query too:

```
SELECT book_count,a.author_id,a.fn, a.ln 
FROM author a
JOIN
(
  SELECT c.author_id,COUNT(*) book_count FROM book c
  GROUP BY c.author_id
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1
) b 
ON a.author_id = b.author_id
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/336d6/51)

Comment: Follow-up question is why `LIMIT`? What's wrong with `MAX()`?

Comment: Because if you use `MAX()` or any aggregate function you have to use `GROUP BY` clause. Wait, just editing if you want to use `MAX()`.

Comment: But still the same result right? I'd rather use the first one since it looks neater. Thanks. Accepted answer.

Comment: @ChristianMark - Yes first one is better. Also using first query (i.e. `LIMIT`) you can also get top 2 or bottom 2 etc. E.g. [Top two](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/336d6/47).

Comment: @AmitSingh - I don't think so. Do you have any example?

Comment: @AmitSingh - Where did I used any column without `GROUP BY` in the first query?

Comment: @AmitSingh - Yeah. Don't worry. You just need some coffee. It's Monday. :) Please clear all comments.

Answer (score 1):

In fact, MySQL has a lack of support SQL's standard, because it allows use aggregate functions w/o GROUP BY clause and returns random data in result. You should avoid the usage of aggregates in that way.

EDIT:
I mean, for example in MySQL you can execute query like this:

```
SELECT
  MAX(a), b, c
FROM
  table
GROUP BY
  b;
```

Which returns random data in c column, and that's terribly wrong.

Comment: Yes but if you will notice and group them by `author_id` the result would be the same as the sub-query.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, it takes max and first row of 'a' table.

Comment: So what are suggesting? You did answer my follow-up question but not the question. +1 though. I can't accept this without the right fix.

Comment: What task are you solving? Do you want to show information about author with the most books?

Comment: No, I want to display the author with the most number of books. But I already accepted answer. Thanks for the effort.

Answer (score 0):

This am wondering this query is running, you used aggregate function with out using group by. When you need to identity the user which has maximum nook count
Please try

```
SELECT (book_count),b.author_id FROM
author a

INNER JOIN 
(
 SELECT c.author_id,COUNT(*) book_count FROM book c
 GROUP BY c.author_id) B
ON

 a.author_id = b.author_id
having book_count=MAX(book_count)
```

Let me know if it works.