# Retrieve records using max and sum of time, if different users have same time, get the record with latest date created

Tags: mysql

Trying to retrieve records by first summing their time_spent, then using max to retrieve the largest record by time. which seems to be working.

I need to now check if on the chance that the sum of time_spent are the same value for users (a tie, like in the example below, both users have time_spent as 10 so it should then select the user that has the latest post), if they are  then I need to only get the user_id that was posted last (newer) using the created_at column. I just don't know what to use to do that check, is it a CASE, or IF Function? and if so where would it go in my query?

Here is a sql fiddle link: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f24985/2

Table1 layout

```
+----+---------+-----------+---------+------------+------------+
| id | user_id | member_id | item_id | time_spent | created_at |
+----+---------+-----------+---------+------------+------------+
| 1  | 1       | 1         | 1       | 5          | 2019-06-01 |
| 2  | 2       | 1         | 1       | 1          | 2019-06-07 |
| 3  | 2       | 1         | 1       | 5          | 2019-06-08 |
| 4  | 2       | 1         | 2       | 4          | 2019-06-01 |
| 5  | 1       | 1         | 2       | 5          | 2019-06-07 |
+----+---------+-----------+---------+------------+------------+
```

Current SQL:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(attribute_time.sum_time), attribute_time.user_id
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            SUM(time_spent) AS sum_time, user_id
        FROM 
            table1
        WHERE 
            member_id = 1
            AND item_id IN (1, 2)
            AND (created_at BETWEEN '2019-06-1' AND '2019-06-30')
        GROUP BY 
            user_id
        ORDER BY 
            sum_time desc
    ) AS attribute_time;
```

In this example, both users have a total of 10 for time, currently returns the first record of the 2 and not based on the created_at date, which in this case, should be user 2.

Expected

```
+---------+
| user_id |
+---------+
| 2       |
+---------+
```

Comment: Can you also add the exact output you are expecting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are looking for. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a5306c/4/0
The MAX clause is problematic for sub-queries involving quantities unless you use some repetitive and verbose queries (DRY!), as seen in answer here: [MySQL: Select MAX() from sub-query with COUNT()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051729/mysql-select-max-from-sub-query-with-count) - it seems to decouple the rows, so you get the highest (max) sum_time with the wrong id (I thought I was seeing things, seemed so simple)

I used LIMIT to get around it. Sorting descending (the highest on top), and then LIMITing the result to 1 achieves the same thing as "Max".

Also - Im not sure if in event of a tie in max time you wanted to pick the earliest or latest record, but this picks the latest. I use MAX to pick the last day/time for each user, and orderby sum_of_time, then by date. If you want the opposite, sub MIN for MAX and/or DESC for ASC in the order-by. Regards! Thx for the exercise.

```
    SELECT 
        SUM(time_spent) AS sum_time, user_id, MAX(created_at)
    FROM 
        Table1
    WHERE 
        member_id = 1
        AND item_id IN (1, 2)
        AND (created_at BETWEEN '2019-06-1' AND '2019-06-30')
    GROUP BY 
        user_id
    ORDER BY
         sum_time DESC, created_at DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thanks Ben, that is working. Sorry for the confusing question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this it will give you user id 2

```
SELECT 
    MAX(attribute_time.sum_time), attribute_time.user_id
    FROM (
        SELECT 
            SUM(time_spent) AS sum_time, user_id
        FROM 
            table1
        WHERE 
            member_id = 1
            AND item_id IN (1, 2)
            AND (created_at BETWEEN '2019-06-1' AND '2019-06-30')
        GROUP BY 
            user_id
        ORDER BY 
            sum_time,user_id desc
    ) AS attribute_time;
```

Comment: hmm, while it did produce user_id 2, if I change a record for user 1 to created_at 2019-06-10, which would be the newest, it still shows user 2 instead of 1

Comment: can you send me sqlfiddel so I can check

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f24985/2

Comment: in your sub query add sum_time, user_id desc it will show user id 2